# Resolution change after my xubuntu 18.04 updated with Nvidia 390 driver

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xubuntu

After updated recently, my pc resolution changed. I am using Nvidia driver 390.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel updated to 5.3 recently. But Ubuntu maintainers forgot to update the 390 Nvidia driver to build with that kernel.

The solution is to install a driver from PPA. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and reboot.

That solved exactly same issue for me.

Comment: thank you very much. It works and recovered well.